# C++ Populate new elements in a resized dynamic array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic, resize

While ripping through my homework, I've run across a bug I can't figure out. I've read and played around it but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

The user enters an `int` pointer array, then the code is supposed double the size of the array and populate the new elements with `0`. The problem is that the new elements aren't `0`. What am I doing wrong and what are these numbers being printed, addresses?

Output:

```
Enter array size: 3
Enter Element 0: 10
Enter Element 1: 11
Enter Element 2: 12

Entered Array:
Element 0/3 is 10
Element 1/3 is 11
Element 2/3 is 12

Resized Array:
Element 0/6 is 10
Element 1/6 is 11
Element 2/6 is 12
Element 3/6 is -33686019
Element 4/6 is 1196933248
Element 5/6 is 201354124

Press any key to continue . . .
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int *createArray(int size)
{
    int *newArray;

    newArray = new int[size];

    for( int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        cout << "Enter Element " << i << ": ";
        cin >> newArray[i];
    }
    return newArray;
}

int *dblArraySize ( int *myArray, int& size)
{
    int *newArray;

    newArray = new int[size*2];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        newArray[i] = myArray[i];

    for (int i = size; i < size*2; i++){
        newArray[i] = 0;
    }

    size = size*2;
    return newArray;         
}

void displayArray(int *anArray, int size, string msg)
{   
    cout <<endl << endl << msg;
    for (int i = 0; i<size;i++){
        cout << endl << "Element " << i << "/" << size << " is " << anArray[i];
    }
}

int main ()
{
    int size,
        *mainArray;

    cout << "Enter array size: ";
    cin >> size;
    mainArray = createArray(size);

    displayArray(mainArray,size, "Entered Array:");

    dblArraySize(mainArray,size);

    displayArray(mainArray,size, "Resized Array:");
}
```

Comment: You can skip out on the second loop by using `new int[size*2]()` to value-initialize (int becomes 0) all elements.

Comment: Ohhh, initialize the new array to zero and then I only need one loop to move the old array over. Sweet, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are returning the newArray from dblArraySize, but never using it. You never modify mainArray

```
 dblArraySize(mainArray,size);
```

Should be:

```
 mainArray = dblArraySize(mainArray,size);
```

Also note: You are forgetting to release the memory for the original array.